# How to get xml file name from query?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a query:

```
insert into #tmpRcIzm
    select distinct
        v.id_art, 'Y'
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_komp/nol') with #vc xd 
        inner join nol v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
    where
        xd.P_REF!=v.P_REF
```

Is it possible to get the xml file name from it? If yes, then how it is done?

Comment: No, you have to save the filename at the point you prepare the XML doc.

Comment: @Ben I have to write the filename in the xml doc?

Comment: Your `@hDoc` comes from `sp_xml_preparedocument`. That requires the raw XML data as input. Where did you get the raw XML? From a file?

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the XML into `@hDoc` (sp_xml_preparedocument).

Comment: @Mikael This is the code where XML loads into [@]hDoc: "EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument [@]hDoc OUTPUT, [@]xmldata"

Comment: Ok. And where does `@XMLdata` come from?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson It comes from C# code

Comment: Do you want the name of the file that is used in the C# code? It does not have to be a file. XML is just a string and carries no information on what file it was stored in. If you want the filename from the c# code in SQL Server you have to provide that as a separate parameter to SQL Server.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Ok. Will do that, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a string and carries no information about what file it was previously stored in.
You have to provide the filename to SQL Server in some other way.